# rails generate error dont know how to build task 'rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm following the basic RoR getting started guide and I have gotten to the point where I run "bin/rails generate controller Welcome index". Everything up until that point works correctly, but when I run that command I get the following error:

```
rails aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'rails' (see --tasks)
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:71:in `[]'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:151:in `invoke_task'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block in top_level'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:117:in `run_with_threads'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:102:in `top_level'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/rake_proxy.rb:13:in `block in run_rake_task'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/rake_proxy.rb:10:in `run_rake_task'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:51:in `run_command!'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:9:in `require'
bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
```

I'm trying to run this on Windows subsystem for Linux so that is probably where this error is stemming from. Does anybody have any insight into fixing this? I've tried remaking the project and reinstalling rails and looking all over the internet for solutions.

Comment: Did you really only type `bin/rails generate controller Welcome index` or did you happen to try to run that as a `rake` command? `rails generate` is correct. `rake rails generate` will get you that error message.

Comment: I definitely did bin/rails. That was one of my first thoughts that I somehow screwed up typing it, but it is most definitely correct :L. Thanks for the suggestion though :D.

Comment: Ah. You're running Rails 5, which rolled rake functions into Rails. This is making more sense now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a known issue of 'Bash On Windows'.

While waiting for a fix from Microsoft, create your new app with "--skip-spring' after 'rails new your_app'

Comment: Thanks a lot dude! That was what I needed! Is there a source for where you found this out? It might be useful in the future if I run into more errors! :D

Comment: Yes of course :) 
https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/451#issuecomment-225936330
if you run into any other errors, just post a new issue on that repo. It's the official Repo of Bash on Windows. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you check again in your console to make sure that you are in your application directory (the directory of the application created when you ran `rails new your_app`)

A simple way to do this is to run the `ls` command in your console and see what it prints.

If you're sure you are indeed within the root directory of the new app, I'd suggest you go back on step (`cd ..`) and then try creating another application (`rails new another_app`). Then `cd another_app` and run the `rails generate` command again.

Comment: Unfortunately I have already tried this several times. Each time I get the exact same error. I've made sure that I am in the correct directory. Is there any more information I could provide that would be useful?

Comment: Does running `rails server` on the console throw an error too ?